# Is there a way to create a count of nonblank cells within a matrix based on columns header and row?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have data currently formatted like **Table 1** below. I need to create a formula to populate the matrix in **Table 2**. Essentially I need to count the non-blank cells if the column and row match. There are duplicates in the columns so I need to aggregate these together. I already have the rows and columns of **Table 2 created**. Any ideas on the easiest way to do this? I already tried a mix of `counta` and `countif` formulas without any luck.

**Table 1**

|  | 1/4/2021 | 1/4/2021 | 1/11/2021 | 1/11/2021 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | V |  | O |  |  |
| Person B | V | V | V | V |  |
| Person C |  | V |  | O |  |

**Table 2**

|  | 1/4/2021 | 1/11/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | 1 | 1 |
| Person B | 2 | 2 |
| Person C | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$E$4<>"")*($A$2:$A$4=$E10)*($B$1:$E$1=F$9))
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

Comment: Only 9,999? Let's make it 10,000 :)